# Flutter desktop maximized

Tags: flutter, windows, dart, cross-platform

I'm trying to learn `Flutter` Desktop, using VS Code on Windows. This seems really basic but I just can't get it to work: I want the app to start maximized. Without modifying the C++ code. I opted for `window_manager` plugin. Here's what I have so far:

```
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';
import 'favorites_page.dart';
import 'generator_page.dart';
import 'settings_page.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Must add this line.
  await windowManager.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MyApp());
  
  WindowOptions windowOptions = WindowOptions(
    //size: Size(800, 600),
  );

  windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow(windowOptions, () async {
    await windowManager.show();
    await windowManager.focus();
    await windowManager.maximize(); // fullscreen window
  });

  //runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I think it appears maximized for a split second but then it reverts back to the default size.

Comment: There is currently a related [open issue](https://github.com/leanflutter/window_manager/issues/412) in GitHub.